# Prove $\frac{1}{n}\in\ell_p$ for $1<p<\infty$ is not product of two elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

The question is as follows

> Prove  $\frac{1}{n}\in\ell_p$ for any  $1<p<\infty$ is not product of two elements

**My Solution**.

Suppose there exist $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(z_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $\ell_p$ such that $\frac{1}{n}=(y_nz_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, so we have $$z_n=\frac{1}{ny_n}, \quad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|y_n|^p<\infty$$ and so
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z_n|^p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{ny_n}|^p$$

I want to get  a contradiction How do I show that?

Can you please help me?

Comment: For $p=3$ (and many other values), we do have $1/n = (1/\sqrt{n})(1/\sqrt{n})$ with $1/\sqrt{n} \in \ell^p$. Could you check your question?